# Run artisan command in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I have controller like this

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
   Artisan::call("php artisan infyom:scaffold {$request['name']} --fieldsFile=public/Product.json");
}
```

Show me error

> There are no commands defined in the "php artisan infyom" namespace.

When I run this command in CMD it work correctly

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You need to remove `php artisan` part and put parameters into an array to make it work:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   Artisan::call("infyom:scaffold", ['name' => $request['name'], '--fieldsFile' => 'public/Product.json']);
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan#calling-commands-via-code

Comment: @Alexey Mezenin, It seems you can help me. This about infyom laravel generator. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40952901/how-to-register-in-the-routes-when-i-add-new-function-with-infyom-laravel-genera

Comment: ```public function checkBooking(Request $request)
{
    Artisan::call('booking:check', []);
}
```

The first argument is your command signature.
if you are not passing external data you can pass in an empty array.

Comment: @Alexey Mezenin can you see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51858447/get-dynamic-value-laravel-eloquent-relation-blade

Answer (score 24):

If you have simple job to do you can do it from route file. For example you want to clear cache. In terminal it would be **php artisan cache:clear** In route file that would be:

```
Route::get('clear_cache', function () {

    \Artisan::call('cache:clear');

    dd("Cache is cleared");

});
```

To run this command from browser just go to your's project route and to clear_cache. Example:

```
http://project_route/clear_cache
```

Answer (score 5):

Apart from within another command, I am not really sure I can think of a good reason to do this. But if you really want to call a Laravel command from a controller (or model, etc.) then you can use `Artisan::call()`

```php
Artisan::call('email:send', [
        'user'    => 1,
        '--queue' => 'default'
]);
```

One interesting feature that I wasn't aware of until I just Googled this to get the right syntax is `Artisan::queue()`, which will process the command in the background (by your queue workers):

```php
Route::get('/foo', function () {
    Artisan::queue('email:send', [
        'user'    => 1,
        '--queue' => 'default'
    ]);
    //
});
```

If you are calling a command from within another command you don't have to use the `Artisan::call` method - you can just do something like this:

```php
public function handle()
{
    $this->call('email:send', [
        'user'    => 1,
        '--queue' => 'default'
    ]);
    //
}
```

Source: https://webdevetc.com/programming-tricks/laravel/general-laravel/how-to-run-an-artisan-command-from-a-controller/

Answer (score 2):

Remove php artisan part and try:

```
Route::get('/run', function () {
    Artisan::call("migrate");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Command Job,**

*Path : {project-path}/app/Console/Commands/RangeDatePaymentsConsoleCommand.php*

This is the Job that runs with the artisan command.

```
class RangeDatePaymentsConsoleCommand extends Command {
    protected $signature = 'batch:abc {startDate} {endDate}';
    ...
}
```

**web.php,**

*Path : {project-path}/routes/web.php*

web.php manage all the requests and route to relevant Controller and can have multiple routes for multiple controllers and multiple functions within the same controller.

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'command'], function () use ($router) {
    Route::get('abc/start/{startDate}/end/{endDate}', 'CommandController@abc');
});
```

**CommandController.php,**

*Path : {project-path}/app/Http/Controllers/CommandController.php*

This Controller is created for handle artisan commands and name can be vary but should be same to web.php Controller name and the function name.

```
class CommandController extends Controller {

    public function abc(string $startDate, string $endDate) {
        $startDate = urldecode($startDate);
        $endDate = urldecode($endDate);

        $exitCode = Artisan::call('batch:abc',
            [
                'startDate' => $startDate,
                'endDate' => $endDate
            ]
        );
        return 'Command Completed Successfully. ';
    }
```

***Request : http://127.0.0.1:8000/command/abc/start/2020-01-01 00:00:00/end/2020-06-30 23:59:59***

It's can be access through the web browser or Postman after startup the server. Run this command to start the php server at *{project-path}*

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8080 public/index.php
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

**Method #1: Using route**

```
Route::get('run-it', function () {
    (new \App\Console\Commands\ThisIsMyCommand())->handle();
});
```

**Method #2: Using command line**

```
php artisan command:this_is_my_command
```