# How to run Artisan command in Ccontroller

Tags: laravel, command, laravel-artisan

I have this command in artisan:

**php artisan tenants:artisan "migrate" --tenant=22**

How can I call this command in Artisan facades?

Comment: I hope this is your answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37236206/run-artisan-command-in-laravel-5

Comment: try  Artisan::call('tenants:artisan migrate --tenant=22') as other answer posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Artisan

```
Artisan::call('tenants:artisan migrate --tenant=22')
```

import right facade

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan

Comment: It says

Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\InvalidArgumentException
The "" argument does not exist.